# Problemas al ejecutar videojuego programado en Visual Studio 2019 C++ en otra computadora

Tags: c++, dll

por favor pedirían puedan ayudarme de forma urgente con el siguiente problema. Resulta que estoy programando un videojuego que es un proyecto CLR de NetFramework en C++. A mi videojuego le hize demasiadas pruebas y funciona a la perfección. El problema sucede cuando intento instalar mi aplicación en otro equipo, el cual me muestra un mensaje que dice que en la ejecución del código, MSVCP140D.dll, ucrtbased.dll y VCRUNTIME140D .dll no se encuentran y por lo tanto no se puede ejecutar el código. El problema son esos 3 dlls. He visto varias soluciones por internet pero nada. Instalé los dlls manualmente y los agregué a mi proyecto pero nada. También modifique el proyecto donde dice Biblioteca en tiempo de ejecución y lo modifiqué a multiproceso y dll multiprocesos pero tampoco funcionó. Espero puedan ayudarme y muchas gracias por su comprensión.

Comment: Hola amigo, Bienvenido al Sitio, He verificado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask], Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Codigo o Ejemplo Minimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Puede que [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51437963/msvcp140d-dll-missing-is-there-a-way-around) te sea de ayuda. Ves que termina en `D`? Estas compartiendo el build de Debug. Configuralo como release, y asegurate de que la computadora en la que lo instales tenga el redistribuible correspondiente.

Comment: Las dll que te faltan en otro ordenador, en qué directorio están en el tuyo? Lo digo porque si están en alguna carpeta del sistema, allí tendrás que copiarlas en el otro ordenador. Y si las pones en la misma carpeta que tú aplicación, tendrás que asegurarte de que puedan ser accesibles, como configurando el PATH para que seran visibles.

Comment: me parece que son preguntas duplicadas: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/497005/problemas-al-ejecutar-videojuego-programado-en-visual-studio-2019-c-en-otra-co