# Problemas al ejecutar videojuego programado en Visual Studio 2019 C++ en otra computadora

Tags: c++

Por favor pedirían puedan ayudarme de forma urgente con el siguiente problema. Resulta que estoy programando un videojuego en visualstudio 2019 que es un proyecto CLR de NetFramework en C++. A mi videojuego le hize demasiadas pruebas y funciona a la perfección. El problema sucede cuando intento instalar mi aplicación en otro equipo, el cual me muestra un mensaje que dice que en la ejecución del código, MSVCP140D.dll, ucrtbased.dll y VCRUNTIME140D .dll no se encuentran y por lo tanto no se puede ejecutar el código. El problema son esos 3 dlls. He visto varias soluciones por internet pero nada. Instalé los dlls manualmente y los agregué a mi proyecto pero nada. Configuré mi proyceto como release y lo volví a compilar y no funcionó. También modifiqué el proyecto donde dice Biblioteca en tiempo de ejecución y lo modifiqué a multiproceso y dll multiprocesos pero tampoco funcionó. Espero puedan ayudarme porque ya llevo muchos días sin resolver el problema. Muchas gracias por su comprensión.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaría hacer el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Me parece que a tu POST le falta un Código o Ejemplo Mínimo Reproducible, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Comment: Y al compilar en release, te aseguraste de que la computadora en la que lo compartiste tenga el redistribuible que le hace falta? Esos los puedes bajar desde el sitio de microsoft.